# How to combine 1 or more values of a column with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have done this before but I forgot where in my app I have this code.

I have the following data for ex:

```
Room Type         Extras           Price
Deluxe            Extra Person     150
Super Deluxe      Extra Person     150
Deluxe            Breakfast        250
Super Deluxe      Breakfast        250
Junior Suite      Extra Person     200
```

Now I want to return something from this table using mysql like:

```
Room Type                     Extras           Price
Deluxe & Super Deluxe         Extra Person     150
Deluxe & Super Deluxe         Breakfast        250
Junior Suite                  Extra Person     200
```

The idea here is to group Extras and Price field and get the Room Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Room Type` SEPARATOR ' & ') Type AS `Room Type`,
    Extras,
    Price
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Extras, Price
```